# How do I get access to the .find() method in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know how to use the `find` method, and I want to understand the logic of how I get access to it. I'm trying to figure out how `ActiveRecord` gives access to the `find` method.

As far as I can tell, all models generated inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. According to the source files, the `find` method seems to be located inside the `FinderMethods` module. However, I can't find how, or in what way, `ActiveRecord::Base` is tied with the `FinderMethods` module to give access to the `find` method.

If someone could help explain, that would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, the reason you'll find the method find in
Relation class is to do stuff like:

```
# Assume class User < ActiveRecord::Base
u = User.where('1=1').find(1)
```

If you look deeper:

```
puts User.where('1=1').class.name
=> "ActiveRecord::Relation"
```

And as the Relation class includes the FinderMethods module, the find method will be available as an instance method of the Relation class so you can do the mentioned call:

```
User.where('1=1').find(1)
```

Now, if you wonder why you can do this:

```
User.find(1)
```

You'll have to look at this line in the class ActiceRecord::Base

```
extend Querying
```

And in if you see the ActiveRecord::Querying module you will find this line:

```
delegate :find, :take, :take!, :first, :first!, :last, :last!, :exists?, :any?, :many?, :none?, :one?, to: :all
```

So what happens here is that ActiveRecord::Base will have the class method find because its extending Querying who is delegating the find method through the all method defined in the Relation class.  The key here is understanding what delegates do and here's the place to do that:

https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
$ grep include.FinderMethods . -r
./activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation.rb:    include FinderMethods, Calculations, SpawnMethods, QueryMethods, Batches, Explain, Delegation
```

Comment: I'm in the process of understanding inheritance and include/extend modules, so to me it doesn't make sense how ActiveRecord::Base can provide access to the .find() method when relation.rb is not even mentioned in the base.rb file. Where is the connection I'm missing?

Comment: Rails uses some tricks to avoid excess `require 'relation'` lines. Can you find a Constant that `relation.rb` defines and `base.rb` uses?

Answer (score 0):

FinderMethods are part of ActiveRecord::Relation not ActiveRecord::Base.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L18

ActiveRecord::Relation is the **query that will run on the database** while ActiveRecord:Base is the **instance of the row/s** from ActiveRecord::Relation.